# Get duration in microseconds

Tags: java-8, duration

Considering the exemple :

```
final Duration twoSeconds = Duration.ofSeconds(2);
//      final long microseconds = twoSeconds.get(ChronoUnit.MICROS); throws UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Micros
final long microseconds = twoSeconds.toNanos() / 1000L;
System.out.println(microseconds);
```

I wonder if there is a nicer way to get a Duration in microseconds than converting manually from nanoseconds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wouldn’t use the `java.time` API for such a task, as you can simply use

```
long microseconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(2);
```

from the [concurrency API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) which works since Java 5.

However, if you have an already existing `Duration` instance or any other reason to insist on using the `java.time` API, you can use

```
Duration existingDuration = Duration.ofSeconds(2);
// Since Java 8
long microseconds8_1 = existingDuration.toNanos() / 1000;
// More idiomatic way
long microseconds8_2 = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(existingDuration.toNanos());
// Since Java 9
long microseconds9 = existingDuration.dividedBy(ChronoUnit.MICROS.getDuration());
// Since Java 11
long microseconds11 = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(existingDuration);
```

Comment: .dividedBy(Duration) does not even compile.

Comment: @CristianBotiza indeed, somehow the dependency to a newer Java version slipped though. Added a clarification. Thanks for your note.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Looks like I need to move to Java 11+ :)

Answer (score 7):

Based on Holger answer, my favorite would be:

```
final long microseconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros(twoSeconds.toNanos())
```

Comment: It works fine for 2 seconds. If the original `Duration` is longer than `Long.MAX_VALUE` nanoseconds, then `toNanos()` will throw an exception, which is not really satisfactory in the cases where a good conversion exists (in the case where it is not longer than `Long.MAX_VALUE` *microseconds*).